# error in sending SMS android

Tags: android

hello i am making an adroid application that encrypt and decrypt SMS. i have a problem that when the size of the sms is more than 80 characters the sms can't be send and the app. stop working(gives error)(less than 80 characters no error and i can send SMS).i am converting the message at first to byte(`UTF-8`) then encrypt and send it using `getBytes()`.

this is the error in logcat:

```
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333):android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1328)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333):android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1276)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333):atcom.android.internal.telephony.ISms$Stub$Proxy.sendText(ISms.java:369)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333):atandroid.telephony.SmsManager.sendTextMessage(SmsManager.java:87)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333):atcom.cryptosms.MainActivity.sendSMS(MainActivity.java:296)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333):atcom.cryptosms.MainActivity$3.onClick(MainActivity.java:142)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333):at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2485)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333):atandroid.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:9080)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333): atandroid.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333): atandroid.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333): atandroid.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333):atjava.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333):atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333):atcom.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
06-05 12:16:42.460: E/AndroidRuntime(333): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you tried to encrypt the string with more than 80 char ?

Comment: This is a parsing error for the content you pass in the sms. Do you have any special characters involved? Have you handled them suitably?

Comment: yes i enter 80 characters or more but also i get the same error, less than 80 it is ok and i can encrypt and decrypt. no i don't have any special characters just letters and numbers. hint: i am using sendTextMessage().

Answer (score 0):

Hi try with the below code to encrypt and decrypt.

```
import java.security.SecureRandom;

import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

/**
 * Usage:
 * <pre>
 * String crypto = SimpleCrypto.encrypt(masterpassword, cleartext)
 * ...
 * String cleartext = SimpleCrypto.decrypt(masterpassword, crypto)
 * </pre>
 * @author ferenc.hechler
 */
public class SimpleCrypto {


    public static void main(String args[])
    {


        try {

            String sr=encrypt("username", "The AsyncTask isn’t the only way to do background processing in Android, though. The Loader class is a much newer construct in Android (although now it’s getting a bit dated). It was released with Honeycomb(3.0) and is now included in the Support Library. The beauty of the Loader is that it handles some of the ‘gotchas’ that usually are missed when using the AsyncTask. Mainly, it handles activity configuration changes (IE when the user rotates the screen)");
            System.out.println(" &&&& " + sr);
            System.out.println("88888 "+decrypt("username", sr));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
        public static String encrypt(String seed, String cleartext) throws Exception {
                byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
                byte[] result = encrypt(rawKey, cleartext.getBytes());
                return toHex(result);
        }

        public static String decrypt(String seed, String encrypted) throws Exception {
                byte[] rawKey = getRawKey(seed.getBytes());
                byte[] enc = toByte(encrypted);
                byte[] result = decrypt(rawKey, enc);
                return new String(result);
        }

        private static byte[] getRawKey(byte[] seed) throws Exception {
                KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
                SecureRandom sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
                sr.setSeed(seed);
            kgen.init(128, sr); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
            SecretKey skey = kgen.generateKey();
            byte[] raw = skey.getEncoded();
            return raw;
        }


        private static byte[] encrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] clear) throws Exception {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(clear);
                return encrypted;
        }

        private static byte[] decrypt(byte[] raw, byte[] encrypted) throws Exception {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
                Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            byte[] decrypted = cipher.doFinal(encrypted);
                return decrypted;
        }

        public static String toHex(String txt) {
                return toHex(txt.getBytes());
        }
        public static String fromHex(String hex) {
                return new String(toByte(hex));
        }

        public static byte[] toByte(String hexString) {
                int len = hexString.length()/2;
                byte[] result = new byte[len];
                for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
                        result[i] = Integer.valueOf(hexString.substring(2*i, 2*i+2), 16).byteValue();
                return result;
        }

        public static String toHex(byte[] buf) {
                if (buf == null)
                        return "";
                StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer(2*buf.length);
                for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
                        appendHex(result, buf[i]);
                }
                return result.toString();
        }
        private final static String HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
        private static void appendHex(StringBuffer sb, byte b) {
                sb.append(HEX.charAt((b>>4)&0x0f)).append(HEX.charAt(b&0x0f));
        }

}
```